# how to reset a counter every new day using pandas and numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

There are 2 columns in a excel sheet("input.xlsx") : "Time(min)"and "Date". First I want to convert these columns in numpy array, because I want to use these values for further use. Time column is increasing by 15 mins and I want at every next 15 mins the counter column value increases by 1. Also, I want that counter value to get reset on every new day.

desired output(Console result(Not in Xlsx format)):

```
Time(min)        Date       counter  
00:00        27-Aug-18      1
00:15        27-Aug-18      2
00:30        27-Aug-18      3
00:45        27-Aug-18      4
01:00        27-Aug-18      5
01:15        27-Aug-18      6
.
.
.
23:45        27-Aug-18     96
00:00        28-Aug-18     1
00:15        28-Aug-18     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['counter'] = 1
df['counter'] = df[['counter','Date']].groupby('Date').transform(lambda x: x.cumsum())
```

**Edit**: Outputting as numpy arrays

The two numpy arrays would be `data` and `counter`.

- `data` - Contains `Time` and `Date`
- `counter` -Contains the counter column

```
df = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx', header=0)

# Data as it is (DateTime objects and Timestamp objects)
data = df.to_numpy() 
# Or convert all entries to strings
data = df.astype(str).to_numpy()

df['counter'] = 1
counter = df[['counter','Date']].groupby('Date').transform(lambda x: x.cumsum()).to_numpy()
```

Comment: actually i need values in the numpy array format, i have already mentioned that in my question.

Comment: What's a numpy array format? Do you want a numpy array from the df? if so simply use `df.to_numpy()`. But if you want to do the full computation in numpy, not sure if you can achieve that as elegantly as in Pandas.

Comment: Review: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). Right now I mark your answer for deletion.

Comment: I need to store the value of first two columns "Time(min)" and "Date"into numpy array and then calculate the values for "counter " and show these "counter" array"values in the console (not in excel format).

Comment: @nipunvats, let me get this straight. So you want to have two numpy arrays 1) contains Time and Date 2) contains the counter. As long as these two are numpy arrays at the end, you are okay to use the above computation?

Comment: @thushv89 yes, because this is not the only thing that I have to do in my project. Basically I want to use these counter values for further calculations and after that I want to show the result in Excel file not before.

Comment: @nipunvats, updated my answer. See if that works out for you :)